# Calling web service using Famo.us framework

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I just want to Connect to database and call Web Services to get dynamic data from database.

is there any tutorial for Connecting Famo.us and Webservice??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Famo.us doesn't give a damn about your data. Merely the presentation.

I recommend you combine Famo.us with a clientside MVC framework and "bind" the data from our server with the content displayed in your famo.us view.

Or use jQuery AJAX to fill the content property of your surface/widget...

But definately don't think of famo.us as the be all and end all of what you'll need when building JS Apps.

Answer (score 0):

While Famo.us doesn't care how you get your data they do have a little helper function to do a basic GET request in their famous/utilities/Utility class called loadURL() that takes a URL as the first argument and a callback that will receive the data returned from the URL.

I'm not aware of any full blown tutorials on tying in web services with famo.us.

Probably the simplest thing to do, without having to load up jQuery is to use something like the ajax lib by ForbesLindesay on github, https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/ajax that will allow you to do calls the same as jQuery does to a web service to get data back or update data.  There are plenty of resources online that talk about doing that, the difference would just be that you are working with famo.us rather than jQuery to update the UI.